# Icons don't work after publish

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

I have a simple application. When you click a button, the tasbar icon changes. When I Run this app from visual studio, everything works fine, but when I publish the WPF app, the taskbar Icon does not work (there is none).

The build action is set to "embedded resource/copy always", I have tested "Resource" as well but it doesn't work.

```
var iconUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/internet_connection.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        this.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri);
```

the icon in the top left corner of the frame changes, but the one in the taskbar doesn't.

Can anyone help me please ?

@Edit,

I got it to work thanks to @Pavel's comment. But now one problem remains:

When I run it in visual studio, and I do this:

```
var iconUri = UriHelper.GetUri(this.GetType(), "images/local_network.ico");
        this.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri);
```

The Icon changes. But with the published version, it doens't change.

@@Edit,

Ok so this is my code when I press a button:

```
  var iconUri = UriHelper.GetUri(this.GetType(), "images/internet_connection.ico");
        this.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri);
        mNotifyIcon = new NotifyIcon
        {
            BalloonTipText = "The app has been minimised. Click the tray icon to show.",
            BalloonTipTitle = "The App",
            Text = "The App",
            Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri)
        };

        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.UriSource = UriHelper.GetUri(this.GetType(), "images/internet_connection.png");
        image.EndInit();
        TaskbarItemInfo = new System.Windows.Shell.TaskbarItemInfo() { Overlay = image };
```

what does it do:
When running from VS: the icon in the taskbar changes, the overlay works, the icon in the top corner of the application changes.

After build running the exe:  the icon in the taskbar DOES NOT change, the overlay works, the icon in the top corner of the application changes.

Can anyone explain this ?

Comment: I remember a similar issue once, but can't remember the details.  It was something to do with the pack not being in the bin folder, or not having the resource in a bin folder inside the pack.  Don't have time to look it up just now though, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this line works for you (you have forgot the ...;component/....):

```
var iconUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourProjectName;component/images/internet_connection.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

for the icon use

```
Build Action = Resource
Copy to OutputDirectory = Do not copy
```

Comment: This gives an error, even in visual studio when I run. Before, it worked in visual studio.

Comment: by running this line:     iconUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/SwitchLive;component/images/local_network.ico", UriKind.Relative); I get: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'SwitchLive.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.

Comment: That problem is allready solved, I have a new problem, can you check my @Edit please :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to set build action in 'Resource' and use a helper:

```
public static class UriHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets absulute URI for provided relative path
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="baseType">Base type for ussage as URI root</param>
    /// <param name="relativePath">Relative path</param>
    /// <returns>Absolute Uri</returns>
    public static Uri GetUri(Type baseType, string relativePath)
    {
        Assembly oAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(baseType);
        AssemblyName oName = oAssembly.GetName();
        return new Uri( 
                String.Format(
                    "pack://application:,,,/{0};v{1};component/{2}",
                    oName.Name,
                    oName.Version.ToString(),
                    relativePath), 
                UriKind.Absolute);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the basetype variable ?

Comment: @Nealv baseType is any type in the assembly to which resource is attached.

Comment: Ok, this work thank you allready, but no I have one other problem. Can you checkt the edit on my question pretty please.

Comment: @Nealv Are you rebiuld entire solution before publish? Is in configuration manager for Release build configuration the Build flag for your project checked? It looks like you deploy old assemblies on server.

Comment: Yes I do a new build and the build flag is checked.

Comment: @Nealv I absolutely sure that code is OK. Publish issues is always about cache. Ensure you correctly set up caching in case you use click once for application delivery. If you use setup project remember that you should rebuild solution and than rebuild and publish setup project. In any case you can check your published assemblies with [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) to ensure that code is there after publish.